# Blogger Conditional Tag If a Post has Spesific Label

Tags: javascript, blogger

im trying to Execute some Javascript code like this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('dark-Mode'), {})
    myModal.toggle()
    document.querySelector("#mainCont").classList.add("drK")
    
    //]]>
    </script>
</b:if>
```

that script is work fine, but the problem is I only want to execute it in post page that has a spesific label. Let say that the Dark Mode is automaticaly Turned On in Post that has Games label. Im new to Blogger platform, how exactly to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "game"'>
<!-- for label 'game' -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('dark-Mode'), {})
    myModal.toggle()
    document.querySelector("#mainCont").classList.add("drK")
    
    //]]>
    </script>
</b:if>
```

source: [ultimatebloggerguide](https://ultimatebloggerguide.blogspot.com/2016/07/blogger-conditional-tags-for-page-types.html)